# jQuery Masonry - re-align tiles when removed

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a script on the page that removes "tiles" using a filter.

Is it possible to re-align everything when tiles are removed?

This doesn't seem to be doing it:

```
  $wrapper.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
```

I'm using the following to filter:

```
$('.tags:not(.tags:contains('+filter_text+'))').parent().fadeOut('slow');
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "remove" method of Masonry for removing elements instead of removing them using jQuery yourself.

So, instead of:

```
$wrapper.find(<filter criteria>).remove();
```

Do:

```
$wrapper.masonry("remove", $wrapper.find(<filter criteria>));
```

Comment: this is what I'm currently using... $('.tags:not(.tags:contains('+filter_text+'))').parent().fadeOut('slow');

Comment: So, you're fading them out and not really removing them from the DOM.

Comment: After the fade out animation is done, do what I suggested on the same set of elements.

Comment: what's the syntax for that?

Comment: Either pass a completion callback as the second argument, or use `.promise()` on the affected elements. Please see: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ and http://api.jquery.com/promise/#example-1